# Does the Skiplagged web site check if round trip is cheaper?

Tags: price, one-way

On the Skiplagged site, I put in a one way (BCN - CLT) and the only flights under $750 were over 40 hours!  The I clicked "round trip" and it gave me many 15 hour flights for under $750.

Is the Skiplagged site faulty in not checking to see if the round trip is cheaper, or is that documented somewhere that it's up to the user to check the round trip.

The site seems to be all about throwing away air travel legs, so why not throw away the entire return ticket if it's less expensive and more convenient than the one way?

Comment: My guess is that there are two many possibilities to check if there is no input return date.

Comment: Good point on the too many possibilities.  A new feature might be where the site could check just one return date, and if the ticket was cheaper, alert the user to begin shopping round-trips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask for a one way, it will only show you a one way.

Buying a round trip and throwing away the second half is frowned upon by airlines, as are many of the other ways SL suggests.  Caveat Emptor

Comment: Huh? Skiplagged is obviously not playing by the airlines' rules. Throwing away legs of an itinerary is hardly different than trowing away return flights.

Comment: Following through a full booking I came to discover that SL doesn't book, rather they look up potential ways to buck the system, then let you book the ticket and thus bear any additional costs or penalties if the airlines determine you have violated airline policy.  But my first statement is still accurate (ask for one way, get one way results).

Comment: The first sentence answers it.  Thanks.  I think the site should be updated to try one return date for international flights and, if cheaper, shop a few random future dates.